# Alert once (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, cookies, alert

Is it possible to alert a user just once about something on his first visit? Can't use cookies because its a static site, only html and javascript are used.

Thanks!

Comment: I would immediately leave a site that opens with a JS alert and never come back...

Comment: Me too, but I would alert every sec, if I could, if you're on IE6, thats what this is about. ;)

Comment: BTW, I mean an HTML alert, not an alert dialog.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use cookies if it's only HTML and JavaScript... JavaScript can read/write cookies to the browser.

I would set a real basic cookie value, and check that before alerting what you need.

You can use [this code](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) (scroll down) to read/write cookies and then do something like this:

```
// if the cookie doesn't exit, 
// it means it's the first time the user is visiting this page
if(!readCookie('boom')) {

   // this will only run the first time
   alert("something");

   // now set the cookie value "boom" for 7 days
   createCookie('boom','1',7);
}
```

Comment: Those functions are great and very useful, but I need to save lines here because I just need it once. Thanks!

Comment: @Luca what may be a solution for this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347654/combo-box-is-getting-vanished-when-an-alert-is-coming

Answer (score 1):

> Can't use cookies because its a static
>   site, only html and javascript are
>   used.

You can still use [cookies with javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

Comment: what may be a solution for [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9347654/combo-box-is-getting-vanished-when-an-alert-is-coming)